# Wix: HarvestDirectory target for multiple directories

Tags: msbuild, wix

I'm trying to harvest different folders in my *.wixproj file. But HeatDirectory task is only harvesting last HarvestDirectory target. What I'm missing here?

Here is my code segment:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Components.wxs">
      <Link>Components.wxs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Product.wxs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="$(SolutionDir)\WebApplication2\bin\$(Configuration)">
      <AutogenerateGuids>true</AutogenerateGuids>
      <ComponentGroupName>SimpleWebAppGroup</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressCom>true</SuppressCom>
      <SuppressRegistry>true</SuppressRegistry>
      <PreprocessorVariable>var.SourceDir</PreprocessorVariable>
     <Visible>false</Visible>
    </HarvestDirectory>

    <HarvestDirectory Include="D:\testing\TTSVN\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Common\TortoiseOverlays">
      <AutogenerateGuids>true</AutogenerateGuids>
      <ComponentGroupName>SVNOverLays</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>PROGFILES</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressCom>true</SuppressCom>
      <SuppressRegistry>true</SuppressRegistry>
      <PreprocessorVariable>var.SourceDir</PreprocessorVariable>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
    </HarvestDirectory>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <HeatDirectory NoLogo="$(HarvestDirectoryNoLogo)"
                   SuppressAllWarnings="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressAllWarnings)"
                   SuppressSpecificWarnings="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressSpecificWarnings)"
                   ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
                   TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(HarvestDirectoryTreatWarningsAsErrors)"                       TreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors="$(HarvestDirectoryTreatSpecificWarningsAsErrors)"
                   VerboseOutput="$(HarvestDirectoryVerboseOutput)"
                   AutogenerateGuids="$(HarvestDirectoryAutogenerateGuids)"
                   GenerateGuidsNow="$(HarvestDirectoryGenerateGuidsNow)"
                   OutputFile="Components.wxs"
                   SuppressFragments="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments)"
                   SuppressUniqueIds="true"
                   Transforms="%(HarvestDirectory.Transforms)"
                   Directory="@(HarvestDirectory)"
                   ComponentGroupName="%(HarvestDirectory.ComponentGroupName)"
                   DirectoryRefId="%(HarvestDirectory.DirectoryRefId)"
                   KeepEmptyDirectories="false"
                   PreprocessorVariable="%(HarvestDirectory.PreprocessorVariable)"
                   SuppressCom="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressCom)"
                   SuppressRegistry="%(HarvestDirectory.SuppressRegistry)"
                   SuppressRootDirectory="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressRootDirectory)"
                   >

    </HeatDirectory>
  </Target>
```

If I omit HeatDirectory task, it would definitely not updating Component.wxs. I didn't find any example showing the use of HarvestDirectory with HeatDirectory task. While [Wix documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html) shows that HarvestDirectory target passes HarvestDirectory items to the HeatDirectory task to generate authoring from a file.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: hey, why the -ve point?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dropped HarvestDirectory items and now using two HeatDirectory tasks, while generating two separate wxs files, while linking in Compile. This solved the problem....